# jquery on Click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my script by which i am firing event

```
   $("#drg_table").closest('tr td').click(function(){     
                    alert('i am here');
                });
```

and this is my table

```
       <table name="drg_table">
<tbody>
<tr id="hospital_name" name="hospital_name">
<td>hospital_name</td>
<td>Average Covered Charges</td>
<td>Average Total Payments</td>
<td>Total Discharges</td>
</tr>
<tr id="GREEN CLINIC SURGICAL HOSPITAL" name="GREEN CLINIC SURGICAL HOSPITAL">
<td>GREEN CLINIC SURGICAL HOSPITAL</td>
<td>2701.72727272727</td>
<td>2821</td>
<td>11</td>
</tr>......</tbody></table>
```

But event is not firing at all

Comment: the selector `$("#drg_table").closest('tr td')` is wrong....

Comment: @karthikr: Tried that already but that was also not working.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/   ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drg_table` is the name attribute not an `id`. Additionally you just used `.closest()`. Actually it will look for the `ancestor` elements, not the `descendants`.

Try,

```
$("table[name='drg_table'] tr td").click(function(){     
      alert('i am here');
});
```

Comment: Yes, although I would say that he should just switch the name to id.
example: <table id="drg_table">

Answer (score 3):

`.closest()` traverses up through the DOM.

In your case, `closest()` can be applied to `td` or `tr td` but not on `table` itself.

Attribute is written in square brackets and id as `#`+id.

Try:

```
$("table[name='drg_table']").find("tr td").click(function(){     
    alert('i am here');
});
```

OR

```
$("table[name='drg_table']").on("click","tr td").click(function(){     
    alert('i am here');
});
```

OR

```
$("table[name='drg_table']tr td").click(function(){     
    alert('i am here');
});
```

Comment: method 3 is what i wanted

Answer (score 2):

The `name` attribute has been deprecated, and your selector is looking for an `id`, so change:

```
<table name="drg_table">
```

To

```
<table id="drg_table">
```

And use:

```
$("#drg_table").on("click","tr td").click(function(){     
    alert('I am here');
});
```